# DataTables: how to set configuration after init?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, datatables, tablepress

I'm using the WordPress plugin [TablePress](https://tablepress.org/) for tables. It creates [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) tables which I'd like to **modify after init**.

**Problem**: the tables are **already initialized** by the plugin, which means I can't use the constructor anymore.

```
// Already set by the plugin:
$('#tablepress-1').dataTable({
    columnDefs: [
        { targets: -1, className: 'dt-body-right'}
    ]
});
```

I'm looking for something like that (pseudocode):

```
var table = $('#tablepress-1').dataTable();
table.updateConfig({
    columnDefs: [
        { targets: -1, className: 'dt-body-right'}
    ]
})
```

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not so clear exactly what you want to modify. Many options cannot be modified, and to modify for example `columnDefs` require re-initialisation (which needs `destroy: true`). If the options you want to modify is generic / static you can extend [DataTables defaults](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/defaults.html):

```
$.extend( true, $.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
  columnDefs: [
    { targets: '_all', className: 'dt-body-right' } // _all not -1
  ]
})
```

`className` and any other `default` can still be overwritten by the options 
passed to the constructor.  If that is the problem you can "monkey patch" DataTables:

```
const orgDT = $.fn.DataTable
$.fn.DataTable = function(config) {
   config.columns[0].className += ' table-success'
   return orgDT.call(this, config)
}
```

This gives 100% control over however this "tablepress" initalise DataTables - the config is simply picked up and can be altered before the table is instantiated.